# Is Jensens equation when F(0)=0 and F(1)=1 identical to cauchy functional equation in the rational, non continous case

Tags: probability, continuity, convex-analysis, linear-transformations, functional-equations

Technically (jensen equation) as f(x+y)=F(x)+F(y) when F(0)=0 and I can see how given the unit f(1)=1, one could effectively capture (numerically) powers of three , 7 etc, in a probability setting, and how this  can be generalized, but I am not convinced, that the two equations  literally the same in the finite case (before continuity is applied, just with F(0)=0 and F(1)=1 if need be in a probability setting. Can it express this in a functional manner for all rational sigma F(sigma(x+y))=F(sigma \timesx)+f(sigma\timesy)

Whilst cauchy's equation and jensens equation could be considered functionally equivalent given continuity and f(0)=0 etc), are they identical in the dense infinite (but rational) cases at least when f(0)=0.

For example can it precisely but can it precisely express F(x+y +z_=F(x)+F(y)+F(z) for all rationals; and does it entail rational homogeneity before continuity as applied as does cauchy's equation.

For all real numbers F(x+y)=F(x)+F(y) and for all real numbers where for all rat sigma, F(sigma\times A)= sigma times F(A)in this form or in the additive jensen form athough it appears to be satisfies conditionally for all x though, and the numerically results bear it out.

Comment: I read here https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-9637-4_7#page-1 the following: 
"It is well-known that a function $f$ between a real vector spaces with $f(0)=0$ is a Jensen function if and only it it is an additive function (see [258, 278]). "
Additive function is a function satisfies Cauchy's equation.

Comment: Yes, it will satisfy it; I presume the fact we are considering real vector spaces (forgive if i appear to be talking nonsense) presume a form of metric or continuity. I am wondering whether they are literally logically equivalent in when considering rational numbers and rational homogeneity, ie before it continuity or constraint, or space, renders them identical.

Comment: Does jensens equation, that ism for F(0)=0; exactly imply Pr(sigma A)=sigma Pr(A) where sigma, is any rational number, and A real number; and rational additivity is preserved over irrational numbers. I suppose it does as 2F((A/2+B/2)=F(A)+F(B), where A and B are irrational, presuming A+B is irrational as well,  where the doubling/ halving induced with PR(0)=0 ensures thatF(A)+F(B)= 2F(1/2(A+B))=2/2F(A+B)=F(A+B) I suppose, the change of variable used for halving transformation changes something.

Comment: ThusF(A+B+C+D+E)=F(A)+F(B)+F(C)+F(D)+F(E); likewise with F(3x)=3F(x) etc. through similar arguments by lettzing B=2z, A =z F(A+B)=F(3z)=F(z +(2z))=F(z)+F(2z), doubling F(0), thus it = F(z)+2F(z)=3F(z); F(3z)=F(z) direclty.  I think knew that it did, i was a bit being obsessive I suppose depending on whethers these are conditional jensen equations and the different uses of the change of variables (ie where a model is (locally jensen, for, pairs of points for all pairs,, where the numerical result appears to be, or nearly the the same but one cannot express this functionally as easily